# Flume - Is it possible to stop only a flume source?

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I've a flume memory channel and I want to know if exists a way to be sure that stopping a flume agent will not cause data loss on the channel.

A possible solution could be to stop the source, attend that the channel is flushed and then stop the agent.

Is there another way to stop a flume agent without loss data?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: If you want to protect against data loss, memory channel is not recommended.

You should consider using either File channel or Kafka channel. For further information, please see https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#flume-channels

Explanation: even if you ensure that the Flume source is completely stopped and the memory channel is flushed, you may have power outages or system failures which lead to data loss that you are trying to avoid.